# Can't cope with images uploaded by a user during development

Tags: django

**Django 1.9.7**

Could you help me cope with user uploaded images. I have managed to save images.

But I can't show them. So far this is all about **development** stage (not production).

The bottommost code sample shows the html when I execute "View page source" in Chrome. This "src="/home/michael/workspace/..." is absolute path. It will work if I create such html and open it in the browser without a webserver.

But whey I run the Django dev server, the image doesn't show.

Could you give me a kick here.

**/pharchive/pharchive/settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../media/')
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../media/')
```

**/pharchive/pharchive/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**/pharchive/masterdocument/models.py**

```
class Image(AbstractDocument):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
```

**/pharchive/masterdocument/views.py**

```
class ImageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Image
```

**/pharchive/masterdocument/templates/masterdocument/image_detail.html**

```
<html>
    <img src="{{ object.image.url }}"/> 
</html>
```

**view-source:http://localhost:8000/images/6/**

```
<html>
    <img src="/home/michael/workspace/pharchive/media/images/2016/06/29/Screenshot_from_2016-02-23_205205.png"/>    
</html>
```

Comment: If you are only concerned about development like you said, then adding `file://` in front of the url will make it "work" for a while.

Comment: well, I am now in development stage. What you say is hardcoding. It will not work in development in future.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "work" yeah. Won't recommend it past the next 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MEDIA_URL` should be the root URL for uploaded media, for example:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

You have set it to the path the the folder where uploaded media are copied.

Edit: as requested more information on how that works.

What you are trying to do is store an image file submitted by a user, and then serve it to other users. To store the file, you need to specify a location on the filesystem where to store it, in your case:

`/home/michael/workspace/pharchive/media/images/2016/06/29/Screenshot_from_2016-02-23_205205.png`

Django builds this path by concatenating these parts:

- the `MEDIA_ROOT`
- the `ImageField`'s interpolated `upload_to` attribute, here `'images/%Y/%m/%d'` interpolated to `images/2016/06/29`
- the file name, here `Screenshot_from_2016-02-23_205205.png`.

Django also stores in the database the path to the file, relative to the `MEDIA_ROOT`, in your case `images/2016/06/29/Screenshot_from_2016-02-23_205205.png`

Now, to serve the stored file to your users, it first needs to be accessible through a URL, this URL is built by concatenating the `MEDIA_URL` setting to the path stored in the database (maybe modified to make it URL compatible), here it gives `/media/images/2016/06/29/Screenshot_from_2016-02-23_205205.png`.

The last step is to actually serve the file when the previously constructed URL is accessed, typically it will not be done the same way in development and in production.

In development, the Django devserver will be used to serve the file, which is why you add a url pattern when `DEBUG` is true. That url pattern will map any URL starting with the `MEDIA_URL` (`/media/`) to a view that will read the stored file and return its content.

In production you will use a dedicated web server to serve uploaded files, for performance reasons.

Comment: Working. I'll accept this answer. But could you just spend another couple of minutes and help me understand what is going on here. I thought that MEDIA_URL is not used in this case at all. So, I just write something in it randomly. And now it appears that this path to productive media files influences showing images in dev stage. This is a mystery to me.

Comment: The `MEDIA_URL` is being used because you're requesting media files that has been uploaded by a user. This is the same when your dev server is requesting static files, it will use the `STATIC_URL` for the request. When you deploy to production or if you have a staging server for testing, you'll need to tell your web-server (like NGINX or Apache) where the static and media files live.